# Buttons with state android

Tags: button, jbutton, imagebutton

Good evening,

I ask myself the following head breaks:

I would like to create a Favorites button that has the two following states:

1st state: "Add to Favorites"

2nd state (on OnClick event): "Remove from favorites"

But I'd also be able to return to the 2nd state: "Add to Favorites" by a 2nd OnClick event ect..

Does anyone have a solution for it with a simple OnClickListener it seems impossible.

I finally solved my problem using a custom checkbox !!Is the best way to use favorite things because you can get the state of your drawable !!

like that :

```
favoris_button = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.star);

            favoris_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                        favoris_button.setText("Supprimer des categories");
                    }
                    else
                        favoris_button.setText("Ajouter aux favoris");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this code inside your listener or wrap a function around it and pass it the boolean and call it when you need to. Startup, reset or whenever you want to change the state. If the button is clicked you need to flip the state.

```
  private Boolean check;
favoris_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.promotion_favoris);      

            favoris_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {

            if (check == true)
            {
                favoris_button.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.btn_orange9);
                favoris_button.setText("Supprimer des favoris");
            }
            else
            {
                favoris_button.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.btn_red9);
                favoris_button.setText("Ajouter aux favoris");
            }
            check ^= true;

                }
            });
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it, but I don't have ADK running to check. Make sure your listener is working. Try placing the check assignment inside the if statement instead of xor.

Comment: check ^= true; is the way it needs to be.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15216/discussion-between-count-zero-and-eento)